# Laravel: how to check for previously run scheduled tasks?

Tags: logging, laravel-5, cron

In the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling) they do not specify how the task scheduler saves the records about the previously run tasks. How can I see that a spcefic task was executed?

Comment: Create an EventScheduler that is executed when you run cron tasks?
(just an idea)